# How to run many "for" loops at the same time?

Tags: java, android

So this is my first app ever on android and in one of my methods, I need 4 for loops to run at the same time. The problem is actually they run one after another and not at the same time. Here is my method :
edited :

```
public void play() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                        if (buttonArray0[i].isChecked()) { //Si le bouton d'indice i est actif, le son est joué.
                            soundPool.play(bongo, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();

    Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                        if (buttonArray1[i].isChecked()) { //Si le bouton d'indice i est actif, le son est joué.
                            soundPool.play(caisse_claire, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread2.start();

    Thread thread3 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                        if (buttonArray2[i].isChecked()) { //Si le bouton d'indice i est actif, le son est joué.
                            soundPool.play(grosse_caisse, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread3.start();

    Thread thread4 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                        if (buttonArray3[i].isChecked()) { //Si le bouton d'indice i est actif, le son est joué.
                            soundPool.play(cymbale, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                        }
                    sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread4.start();
}
```

I made some research and I think I understood that you need threads in a java program to be able to run many things at the same time but I have no idea on how to implement threads in my case even tho I tried several ways with the things I found on the internet. I need some advices to be able to fully understand how this works and how to do it in my case.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Look into AsyncTask

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? How can I transform my method with an AsyncTask? Knowing that my play method is not in the main activity, do i need to create an Asynctask on my main activity or on the same class that contains my play method?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a multi-thread program

This method will make that thread sleep for some seconds but this thread won't go to another for loop unless this for loop is executed.

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Try this

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            //add your for loop here
            sleep(1000);
            handler.post(this);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};

thread.start();
```

If you have different calculation inside the for loop you should create these multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I don't really understand where my play method went in your exemple. Do I need to implement the new thread inside my play method or outside? If it's outside, does that mean that my for loop is also outside my play method?

Comment: Whole for loop should be inside ---> while(true){  // one for loop }

Comment: And why do you add a handler.post(this); at the end? I'm truly sorry for all the questions mate.

Comment: Oh! sorry... That's used when you want to change anything in UI. You can remove ithandler.post(this);

Comment: Oh ok. So if I understand correctly, what you did was creating a thread inside the method, add the loop inside the thread and then with thread.start(); you run the thread you just created with the for loop inside. Am I right?

Comment: Yes... you should implement multiple Thread interfaces like that and start all the different threads together... Then all those for loops inside the different run methods will run simultaneously.

Comment: Ok so I just tried it but now I got the opposite problem. Every single checked toogle button is played at the same time and not once at the time. For instance if i check button 1 on the first array and button 2 on the second array, the sounds should play one after the other with 1000ms between them but they play at he same time instead. It seems like the sleep(millis: 1000) isn't working.

Comment: Don't be sorry... Start all the threads together one by one, thread1.start();
thread2.start();

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem. All the toogle buttons are played at the same time

Comment: It even depends on the hardware, CPU must have multiple cores to run those threads simultaneously.

Comment: It's strange, it really feels like the sleep isn't working, i'll try to dig to see if i can find a way to fix this. Thanks a lot for your help anyway dude !

Comment: Please do click on the Tick mark button to accept this answer, it'll help me a lot... Thank you...